# AWS export image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to export an AMI from AWS. But it gives me a strange error:

> Invalid choice: 'export-image', maybe you meant:
>
> - import-image

I have created a centos machine on ec2 and create an ami from that.
Seems like the command I am trying is not available but I don't think that's true

`aws ec2 export-image --image-id ami-0bbbf5422a9788c0b --disk-image-format VMDK --s3-export-location S3Bucket=my-ami-sohaib,S3Prefix=exports/`

Comment: It looks fine at first sight according to documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/export-image.html Can you execute any other command using AWS CLI?

Comment: You might be using the wrong command. What are you actually wanting to accomplish?

Comment: @nickolay.laptev all other commands are working fine

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am trying to export my AMI to S3

Comment: Do you use the latest AWS CLI version? It doesn’t see a command that exists.

Comment: @nickolay.laptev yes i am using the latest one. This is exactly what i am looking. export command doesn't show only import command is showing

Comment: Do you see help after executing "aws ec2 export-image help" command?

Comment: Is your intention to use [VM Import/Export](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/) to export your disk image for use on VMware ESX, Microsoft Hyper-V or Citrix Xen? If so, this only works for images that were **previously imported** from those environments. Or, if you are just wanting to make a backup/copy of the image, then you should create an AMI (but it stays on AWS).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Oh yes, this is exactly what I was trying to do. You got it right. I can only export AMI which was previously imported by me.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Update to the latest V2 version

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26077547)

Comment: Yes it does... Update to the latest v2 series of AWS CLI and export-image is an a command line function.